# What's the correct format to insert a entity with foreign keys in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I want to save a row of Penatu in database.
I have three entitys.

Have I to create three entitys? or Can I use only  a entity object  for setter the other property to save?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PE_NATU")
public class PeNatu{
private long peNatuId;
private String apeMat;
private String apePat;
private Persona persona;
..................
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="PE_NATU_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
  public long getPeNatuId() {
    return this.peNatuId;
}
etc .....

@Entity
@Table(name="PERSONA")
public class Persona {
private long personaId;
private Set<PeNatu> peNatus;
private TmDocIden tmDocIden;

etc .....
@Entity
@Table(name="TM_DOC_IDEN")
public class TmDocIden{
private String tipoDocId;
private Set<Persona> personas;
etc....
```

is this correct?

```
//Class Service- Impl 
    PeNatu admin=new PeNatu();
    admin.setApePat("Test");
    admin.setApeMat("Test");
    admin.getPersona().setPersonaId(7777)
    admin.getPersona().getTmDocIden().setTipoDocId("05");
    long idInserted= dao.insertarPeNatu(admin)
```

Is this  correct to get the id inserted,I use oracle DB?

```
   //DAO -Impl
   public long insertarPeNatu(PeNatu p) {
   Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
   session.persist(p);
   session.flush();
   return p.natu.getPeNatuId();

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not. If you tried it, you would immediately see that you'd get a NullPointerException, since `admin.getPersona()` will return null, and you're trying to call `setPersonaId()` on it.

You're trying to create a PeNatu and attach it to an *existing* Persona. Since it's existing, you just need to get it from the database (using `Session.get()`), or simply assume it's there and get a proxy to this entity, using `Session.load()`:

```
PeNatu admin=new PeNatu();
admin.setApePat("Test");
admin.setApeMat("Test");
Persona existingPersonaWithId7777 = (Persona) session.load(Persona.class, 7777);
admin.setPersona(existingPersonaWithId7777);
long idInserted= dao.insertarPeNatu(admin);
```

Comment: Is the second  method correct to get the current id inserted?

Comment: I don't know what p.natu is. But yes, it seems correct. Why don't you test it?

Comment: is only p.getPeNatuId(); Thanks.